# Calculus 2 Trigonometric Integrals with odd exponents

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

[image]

I do not know how to go about taking the integral of this. I have tried to break it up so I can take the integral of sin^2(x) sin(x) cos^8(x) cos(x). But then this would require me use the reduction formula for the integral of cos^8(x) I believe. If anyone would spare some time to help me with hints or steps to take I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more boring than that. Note that $\sin^2 x=1-\cos^2 x$, so we are integrating $\sin x(\cos^9 x-\cos^{11} x)$. Let $u=\cos x$ and it's over.

Comment: The "Pythagorean Identity" is the key to these. When _both_ powers are odd in a "trigonometric powers" integral involving sine and cosine, you can take your pick of using sine or cosine as the basis for the substitution.  When only one of those functions has the "odd exponent", use that one for the substitution.  When _both_ are even, use the Identity on the function with the _lower_ exponent, multiply terms out to have all even powers of the other function, and then apply the $ \ \sin^2 x \ \text{or} \ \cos^2 x \ $ substitution "trick".

Comment: Thank you for your time that was the right way to do it, I was just making it more difficult than it had to be. Thank you again.

Comment: You are welcome.